# Reverse of inclusion in Latex

Tags: symbols, math-operators

How can we write the reverse of "inclusion" in Latex style? Like in the second statement here?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

`\supseteq`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ A \subseteq B $ or $ B \supseteq A $.
        
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As an aside, [this site](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is very useful for finding symbols in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Both '\supset' and '\supseteq' can be used for the backwards of
inclusion symbol in LaTeX, which stands for "superset" or
"containing set".

```
$ A \subseteq B $ .

  $ B \supseteq A $.
  
  $A \subset B$.
  
  $B \supset A$.
```

[image: LaTeX Output Image]